# Pyparsing parseaction and lists typerror

Tags: python, pyparsing

For a small language I want to parse expressions of the form `"X [Y,Z,V]"` where `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `V` are natural numbers.

Below is my attempt.

```
from pyparsing import *

class Y():
    def __init__(self, ls):
        self.ls = ls

def MakeCombinedList(tokens):
    print(len(tokens)) # prints 4
    print(tokens)      # [5, 1, 2, 3]
    clist = tokens[1]
    clist.append(tokens[0]) # 'int' attribute object has no attribute 'append'
    return clist

def MakeIntList(tokens):
    nlist = tokens[0].split(",")
    ilist = []
    for n in nlist:
        ilist.append(int(n))
    return ilist

def MakeY(tokens):
    Yobj = Y(tokens[0])
    return Yobj

LEFT_BRACK = Suppress(Literal("["))
RIGHT_BRACK = Suppress(Literal("]"))

NATURAL = Word(nums).addParseAction(lambda n: int(n[0]))
NATURAL_LIST = delimitedList(NATURAL, combine = True)
NATURAL_VEC = LEFT_BRACK + NATURAL_LIST +  RIGHT_BRACK
NATURAL_VEC.addParseAction(MakeIntList)

X = NATURAL + NATURAL_VEC
X.addParseAction(MakeCombinedList)

Y = X
Y.addParseAction(MakeY)


print(Y.parseString("5 [1,2,3]").ls)
```

`MakeIntList` is supposed to transform a string such as `"1,2,3"` into the list `[1,2,3]`.

`MakeCombinedList` is then supposed to append an integer to this list, but the `tokens` received by `MakeCombinedList` are not the single integer and the integer list created from `MakeIntList`, but a list of all the integers, as indicated by my comment.

How can I make `tokens[1]` inside `MakeCombinedList` be the result of calling `MakeIntList`?

Comment: `tokens[1]` is the 2nd element of `tokens` which is of type `int` and hence `clist = tokens[1]` simply assigns an integer to `clist` which has no index or `len`. So when you do `clist.append(tokens[0])`, you are trying to append an integer (`tokens[0]`) to another integer which is not possible. If you want to append the whole list `tokens` to `iList`, you can pass `iList` as an argument to `MakeCombinedList`, make a copy of it, append `tokens` to it and then return it. You can also try `clist = MakeIntList(tokens)` inside the `MakeCombinedList` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines are working against each other, since you use the first to parse separate numeric strings into ints, and then the second just combines them back into a comma-separated string.

```
NATURAL = Word(nums).addParseAction(lambda n: int(n[0]))
NATURAL_LIST = delimitedList(NATURAL, combine=True)
```

The feature you are looking for is `Group`:

```
NATURAL = Word(nums).addParseAction(lambda n: int(n[0]))
NATURAL_LIST = Group(delimitedList(NATURAL))
NATURAL_VEC = LEFT_BRACK + NATURAL_LIST +  RIGHT_BRACK
# no MakeIntList parse action required
```

Now instead of creating a new string and then re-parsing it in a parse action, you use `Group` to tell pyparsing to make a sub-structure of the resulting tokens.

There is also a little confusion going on here:

```
Y = X
Y.addParseAction(MakeY)
```

This will redefine `Y` from the class defined at the top to a pyparsing expression, and you get some weird traceback when trying to accessing its `ls` attribute.

```
Y_expr = X
Y_expr.addParseAction(MakeY)
```

I wrote the `runTests` method to make it easier to do simple expression testing and printing, without having to deal with Py2/Py3 print differences:

```
Y_expr.runTests("""\
    5 [1,2,3]
    """)
```

Shows:

```
5 [1,2,3]
[<__main__.Y object at 0x00000241C57B7630>]
```

Since your Y class just uses the default `__repr__` behavior, you can see the contents better if you define your own:

```
class Y():
    def __init__(self, ls):
        self.ls = ls
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(type(self).__name__, vars(self))
```

Now runTests shows:

```
5 [1,2,3]
[Y: {'ls': 5}]
```

If the purpose of the Y class is to just give you attribute names for your parsed fields, consider using results names instead:

```
X = NATURAL('ls') + NATURAL_VEC

Y_expr = X
#~ Y_expr.addParseAction(MakeY)

# what you had written originally    
print(Y_expr.parseString("5 [1,2,3]").ls)
```

Will just print:

```
5
```